# The meaning of "ruz"

Tags: meaning

> Begob, in the moonlight I’m thinking you are right to choose the other
>   way, and it’s he way I’d choose myself if  had their blood in my veins,
>   on nights like this when we’ve been looking at the full moon, my dog
>   and I, **ever since she ruz**.

This is from ['The Story of Mona Sheehy'](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=37wpDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT1216&lpg=PT1216&dq=%22ever%20since%20she%20ruz%22&source=bl&ots=fdDEyBA8yR&sig=ACfU3U2cIOfQF7CIzYrjf4ZDZSeWCDtaig&hl=ja&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjS6oWli4PiAhWGBKYKHVc5A0gQ6AEwAHoECAAQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22ever%20since%20she%20ruz%22&f=falseV) by Lord Dunsay.

Please teach me the meaning of "ever since she ruz"

Answer (score 2):

"Ruz" here is either a dialect or antiquated variation of "rose." The phrase would apply to the moon, which is [often given the female pronoun in poetic English](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/258367/sun-and-moon-male-or-female).

The narrator and the dog have been looking at the full moon ever since it rose.